# Capital gain tax on stocks for nonresident alien under USA-German tax treaty

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, germany, f1-student-visa

I am trying to understand the tax treaty between USA and Germany but this is a pain. I am in the USA on a student visa and considered to be a nonresident alien for tax purposes. I had some gain from the stock market in the US last year. Not sure what is the tax rate under the treaty. Someone told me that it is 0% in the US and taxed in Germany, but I can't find it in the treaty...